# Why margin top and bottom is missing?

Tags: html, css

```css
.separator {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Separator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>hello</span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span>world</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wonder why `<span class="separator"></span>` do not have margin-top and margin-bottom? The following two pictures can clearly describe my problems.

You can see separator's border is from top to bottom:

[image: Separator border]

But console shows that margin-top and margin-bottom are both 10px:

[image: Console]

So where are the margin-top and margin-bottom?

Answer (score 8):

Top and bottom margins do not affect inline elements because inline elements flow with content on the page. You can set left and right margins/padding on an inline element but not top or bottom because it would disrupt the flow of content. You can set margins on block (or inline-block but it will only look right if you set the vertical align right) because block level elements disrupt the flow of content.

This is from the [CSS2 specification on inline formatting of elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting):

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Span is an Inline element so the margin has no effect vertically(top and bottom). Enclosed your span inside DIV to use horizontal margin.

```
.margin {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.separator {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px;
}

<div class="margin">
   <span>hello</span>
   <span class="separator"></span>
   <span>world</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` tags are default using `inline` display property, and because of that they don't respect vertical margin, they only respect horizontal margin., see the below reference

Section [9.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) of the CSS2 specification states:

> **inline** This value causes an element to generate one or more inline
>   boxes. Further on in the CSS2 specification (section 9.4.2) we get
>   told that inline elements only respect horizontal margins

Block-level elements respect both horizontal and vertical margins whereas inline-level elements only respect horizontal margins.
so if you change your property with inline-block then it will respect that, but then you need to do some further styling in order to achieve the vertical bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.separator {
border: 1px solid #000000;
margin: 10px;
display:inline-block;height:20px;vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Separator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>hello</span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span>world</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```